# T-SQL Multiple grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, grouping

I have follwing data :

```
Product Price   StartDate                   EndDate
Apples  4.9     2010-03-01 00:00:00.000     2010-03-01 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-02 00:00:00.000     2010-03-02 00:00:00.000
Apples  2.5     2010-03-03 00:00:00.000     2010-03-03 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-05 00:00:00.000     2010-03-05 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-06 00:00:00.000     2010-03-06 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-09 00:00:00.000     2010-03-09 00:00:00.000
Apples  2.5     2010-03-10 00:00:00.000     2010-03-10 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-11 00:00:00.000     2010-03-11 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-12 00:00:00.000     2010-03-12 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-13 00:00:00.000     2010-03-13 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-15 00:00:00.000     2010-03-15 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-16 00:00:00.000     2010-03-16 00:00:00.000
```

want to group like `product, price, min(startdate), max(startdate)` but should have grouping in start date and end date as well........ something like below

Desired result

```
Apples  4.9     2010-03-01 00:00:00.000     2010-03-02 00:00:00.000
Apples  2.5     2010-03-03 00:00:00.000     2010-03-03 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-05 00:00:00.000     2010-03-09 00:00:00.000
Apples  2.5     2010-03-10 00:00:00.000     2010-03-10 00:00:00.000
Apples  4.9     2010-03-11 00:00:00.000     2010-03-16 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What is the purpose of the `EndDate` column? It appears to always be equal to `StartDate`. Is this assumption true? If so, please remove the `EndDate` column from your example data. If it's not true, I wish you would provide the most "tricky" data instead of the most uniform/boring data so that people providing answers can determine the proper query to always provide the correct result.

Comment: So just for clarity: even though you show no data for 2010-03-14, you want to see the final row for `Apples` span it as `2010-03-11` through `20100316`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach.

Data:

```
create table t ( producte varchar(50), 
                 price money, 
                 start_date date,
                 end_date date);

insert into t values
( 'apple', 4.9, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01' ),
( 'apple', 4.9, '2012-01-02', '2012-01-02' ),
( 'apple', 8, '2012-01-04', '2012-01-04' ),
( 'cat', 5, '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01' ),
( 'cat', 6, '2012-01-02', '2012-01-02' ),
( 'cat', 6, '2012-01-03', '2012-01-03' );
```

Query:

```
with start_dates as (
  select 
    t.producte, t.price, t.start_date, t.end_date, t.start_date as gr_date    
  from 
    t left outer join 
    t t1 on 
        t.price = t1.price and                         --new
        t.producte = t1.producte and
        t.start_date = dateadd(day,1, t1.end_date )
  where t1.producte is null
  union all
  select 
      t.producte, t.price, t.start_date,t. end_date, gr_date
  from
      t inner join 
      start_dates t1 on  
        t.price = t1.price and                         --new
        t.producte = t1.producte and
        t.start_date = dateadd(day,1, t1.end_date )
)
select t.producte, t.price , min( t.start_date ), max( t.end_date )
from start_dates t
group by  t.producte, gr_date  ,t.price
```

[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e4f8/2/0):

```
| PRODUCTE | PRICE |   COLUMN_2 |   COLUMN_3 |
----------------------------------------------
|    apple |   4.9 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-02 |
|    apple |     8 | 2012-01-04 | 2012-01-04 |
|      cat |     5 | 2012-01-01 | 2012-01-01 |
|      cat |     6 | 2012-01-02 | 2012-01-03 |
```

**Explanation**

This is a recursive CTE expression. Base query take inital dates for each group of prices. Recursive query looks for last data with this price.

Comment: @user1926569, I have updated query after accepted it. Review.

Comment: Please remove any incorrect queries from your answer. The purpose of editing is not provide not a historical record but the *best possible answer*. Having incorrect queries and evidence of how the answer changed over time is not the best possible answer.

Comment: @ErikE, thanks about your comment. fixed. Now is right? Regards.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  product, price, MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date)
FROM    (
        SELECT  product, price, start_date, end_date,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY startDate) rn1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, price ORDER BY startDate) rn2
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
GROUP BY
        product, price, rn2 - rn1
ORDER BY
        product, MIN(start_date), price
```

Comment: it's giving me the same result which

Comment: {select product, price, product, price, MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date) from mytable 
GROUP BY
        product, price
}
will give

Comment: @user1926569: sure, my fault. Please try the updated query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf7ad/16

Comment: Best answer on the page yet! Quassnoi, is there any chance you saw [this post of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614431/how-can-i-detect-and-bound-changes-between-row-values-in-a-sql-table/13618019#13618019)? How long have you known about this subtract Row_Number() technique to find changing groups?

Comment: @ErikE: no, did not see your post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662545/how-do-i-group-on-continuous-ranges and there is also a number of posts on this matter on my blog.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/684c8/16)

```
with t2 as 
(
select t1.*,
(select count(Price) 
  from t 
  where startdate<t1.startdate 
        and Price<>t1.price
        and Product=t1.Product
)
rng  
from t as t1
)
select Product,Price,min(startDate),max(EndDate)  
from t2 group by Product,Price,RNG
order by 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion: for each row, you must find the maximum previous date for which the price is different and you Group on that.  For example, for any line between 2010-03-11 and 2010-03-16, you must retrieve the date 2010-03-10 because this is the maximum previous date for which the price is different (2.5 versus 4.9).  The first row(s) will return a null date but that shouldn't be a problem.

However, for a very long table, this kind of query could become very slow.  Therefore, if you have some speed problem, you should look into the possibility of adding a column and use a cursor to fill it incrementally: you loop through it by date and each time you see a new price, you change its value.  The final Grouping is then trivial.

Here's something:

```
Select Product, Price, Min(StartDate) as StartDate, PreviousDate from (
    Select product, price, StartDate, (Select max (StartDate) from table_2 t3 where t3.price <> t2.price and t3.StartDate < t2.StartDate and t3.Product = t2.Product) as previousDate
    from table_2 t2) SQ

Group by Product, Price, PreviousDate
Order by PreviousDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the best-performing solution so far:

```
WITH Calc AS (
   SELECT *,
      Grp = DateAdd(day, -Row_Number()
         OVER (PARTITION BY Product, Price ORDER BY StartDate), StartDate
      )
   FROM dbo.PriceHistory
)
SELECT Product, Price, FromDate = Min(StartDate), ToDate = Max(StartDate)
FROM Calc
GROUP BY Product, Price, Grp
ORDER BY FromDate;
```

[Try this out yourself](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/034ed/4)

Comment: It does not return what the @op asked for.

Comment: You're right, Quassnoi. I missed that the OP wants to skip gaps. I'll return to this soon.