# SQL to check for 2 or more consecutive negative week values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to count the number of 2 or more consecutive week periods that have negative values within a range of weeks.

Example:

```
Week | Value
201301 | 10
201302 | -5 <--| both weeks have negative values and are consecutive
201303 | -6 <--| 

 Week | Value
201301 | 10
201302 | -5 
201303 | 7
201304 | -2 <-- negative but not consecutive to the last negative value in 201302 

 Week | Value
201301 | 10
201302 | -5 
201303 | -7
201304 | -2 <-- 1st group of negative and consecutive values 
201305 | 0
201306 | -12
201307 | -8 <-- 2nd group of negative and consecutive values
```

Is there a better way of doing this other than using a cursor and a reset variable and checking through each row in order?

Here is some of the SQL I have setup to try and test this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestTwo') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestTwo

CREATE TABLE #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne
(
     [Week] INT NOT NULL
     ,[Value] DECIMAL(18,6) NOT NULL
)

-- I have a condition where I expect to see at least 2 consecutive weeks with negative values
-- TRUE : Week 201328 & 201329 are both negative.
INSERT INTO #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne
VALUES
(201327, 5)
,(201328,-11)
,(201329,-18)
,(201330, 25)
,(201331, 30)
,(201332, -36)
,(201333, 43)
,(201334, 50)
,(201335, 59)
,(201336, 0)
,(201337, 0)

SELECT * FROM #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne
WHERE Value < 0
ORDER BY [Week] ASC


CREATE TABLE #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestTwo
(
     [Week] INT NOT NULL
     ,[Value] DECIMAL(18,6) NOT NULL
)

-- FALSE: The negative weeks are not consecutive
INSERT INTO #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestTwo
VALUES

(201327, 5)
,(201328,-11)
,(201329,20)
,(201330, -25)
,(201331, 30)
,(201332, -36)
,(201333, 43)
,(201334, 50)
,(201335, -15)
,(201336, 0)
,(201337, 0)

SELECT * FROM #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestTwo
WHERE Value < 0
ORDER BY [Week] ASC
```

My SQL fiddle is also here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef54f/2

Comment: look at the LAG function.

Comment: @Randy wow thanks did not know that existed. I am also going to need to treat any possible missing weeks as 0 but this should do me.. I will give that a try.

Comment: The LAG function would be very helpful here indeed, but the question is tagged sql-server-2008. I think LAG is SQL 2012.

Comment: @jods Doh didn't catch that, yea this is for SQL 2008  :(

Comment: Since you say there can be missing weeks, how do we know whether there are 52 or 53 weeks in each year? What is your formula for calculating week number? Without this information I cannot provide you with a query that can handle crossing year boundaries. With this information, I *can* provide you with a really nice one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a combination of EXISTS.

Assuming you only want to know groups (series of consecutive weeks all negative)

--Find the potential start weeks

```
;WITH starts as (
    SELECT [Week]
    FROM #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne AS s
    WHERE s.[Value] < 0
      AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne AS p
        WHERE p.[Week] = s.[Week] - 1
          AND p.[Value] < 0
        )
    )
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
    Starts AS s
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM #ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne AS n
        WHERE n.[Week] = s.[Week] + 1
          AND n.[Value] < 0
        )
```

If you have an index on Week this query should even be moderately efficient.

Comment: Note @Home so not tested -- and drunk. So typo's probably exist.

Comment: Yup this works well, thank you. The only thing it won't work for is when the year changes and there is negative values in weeks 201352 and 201401 for example.. but this is a good start for me.

Comment: ah yeah -- true -- glad to help.

Comment: There is no need for 3 table scans. This problem can be solved with normal SQL in just one `JOIN`. In fact, it can be done without a `JOIN` at all.

Comment: My query will only perform 1 scan if there is an index on the week column -- Unless of course there are many many rows that start such groups of negative sets. That is obviously as long as there is an index on week (covering value) -- will result in seeks.

Comment: Fair enough, @TransactCharlie! (Please tag me when replying and others have commented, or I won't be notified!)

Comment: I updated my answer with performance testing results if you would like to see it.

Answer (score 3):

First, would you please share the formula for calculating week number, or provide a real date for each week, or some method to determine if there are 52 or 53 weeks in any particular year? Once you do that, I can make my queries properly skip missing data AND cross year boundaries.

Now to queries: this can be done without a `JOIN`, which depending on the exact indexes present, may improve performance a huge amount over any solution that does use `JOINs`. Then again, it may not. This is also harder to understand so may not be worth it if other solutions perform well enough (especially when the right indexes are present).

Simulate a `PREORDER BY` windowing function (respects gaps, ignores year boundaries):

```
WITH Calcs AS (
   SELECT
      Grp =
         [Week] -- comment out to ignore gaps and gain year boundaries
         -- Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [Week]) -- swap with previous line
         - Row_Number() OVER
            (PARTITION BY (SELECT 1 WHERE Value < 0) ORDER BY [Week]),
      *
   FROM dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne
)
SELECT
   [Week] = Min([Week])
   -- NumWeeks = Count(*) -- if you want the count
FROM Calcs C
WHERE Value < 0
GROUP BY C.Grp
HAVING Count(*) >= 2
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5920c/1) (1st query)

And another way, simulating `LAG` and `LEAD` with a `CROSS JOIN` and aggregates (respects gaps, ignores year boundaries):

```
WITH Groups AS (
   SELECT
      Grp = T.[Week] + X.Num,
      *
   FROM
      dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne T
      CROSS JOIN (VALUES (-1), (0), (1)) X (Num)
)
SELECT
   [Week] = Min(C.[Week])
   -- Value = Min(C.Value)
FROM
   Groups G
   OUTER APPLY (SELECT G.* WHERE G.Num = 0) C
WHERE G.Value < 0
GROUP BY G.Grp
HAVING
   Min(G.[Week]) = Min(C.[Week])
   AND Max(G.[Week]) > Min(C.[Week])
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5920c/1) (2nd query)

And, my original second query, but simplified (ignores gaps, handles year boundaries):

```
WITH Groups AS (
   SELECT
      Grp = (Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY T.[Week]) + X.Num) / 3,
      *
   FROM
      dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne T
      CROSS JOIN (VALUES (0), (2), (4)) X (Num)
)
SELECT
   [Week] = Min(C.[Week])
   -- Value = Min(C.Value)
FROM
   Groups G
   OUTER APPLY (SELECT G.* WHERE G.Num = 2) C
WHERE G.Value < 0
GROUP BY G.Grp
HAVING
   Min(G.[Week]) = Min(C.[Week])
   AND Max(G.[Week]) > Min(C.[Week])
;
```

Note: The execution plan for these may be rated as more expensive than other queries, but there will be only 1 table access instead of 2 or 3, and while the CPU may be higher it is still respectably low.

Note: I originally was not paying attention to only producing one row per group of negative values, and so I produced this query as only requiring 2 table accesses (respects gaps, ignores year boundaries):

```
SELECT
   T1.[Week]
FROM
   dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne T1
WHERE
   Value < 0
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne T2
      WHERE
         T2.Value < 0
         AND T2.[Week] IN (T1.[Week] - 1, T1.[Week] + 1)
   )
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5920c/1) (3rd query)

However, I have now modified it to perform as required, showing only each starting date (respects gaps, ignored year boundaries):

```
SELECT
   T1.[Week]
FROM
   dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne T1
WHERE
   Value < 0
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM
         dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne T2
      WHERE
         T2.Value < 0
         AND T1.[Week] - 1 <= T2.[Week]
         AND T1.[Week] + 1 >= T2.[Week]
         AND T1.[Week] <> T2.[Week]
      HAVING
         Min(T2.[Week]) > T1.[Week]
   )
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5920c/1) (3rd query)

Last, just for fun, here is a SQL Server 2012 and up version using `LEAD` and `LAG`:

```
WITH Weeks AS (
   SELECT
      PrevValue = Lag(Value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]),
      SubsValue = Lead(Value, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]),
      PrevWeek = Lag(Week, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]),
      SubsWeek = Lead(Week, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY [Week]),
      *
   FROM
     dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne
)
SELECT @Week = [Week]
FROM Weeks W
WHERE
   (
      [Week] - 1 > PrevWeek
      OR PrevValue >= 0
   )
   AND Value < 0
   AND SubsValue < 0
   AND [Week] + 1 = SubsWeek
;
```

### [See a Live Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5920c/1) (4th query)

I am not sure I am doing this the best way as I haven't used these much, but it works nonetheless.

You should do some performance testing of the various queries presented to you, and pick the best one, considering that code should be, in order:

1. Correct
2. Clear
3. Concise
4. Fast

Seeing that some of my solutions are anything but clear, other solutions that are fast enough and concise enough will probably win out in the competition of which one to use in your own production code. But... maybe not! And maybe someone will appreciate seeing these techniques, even if they can't be used as-is *this* time.

So let's do some testing and see what the truth is about all this! Here is some test setup script. It will generate the same data on your own server as it did on mine:

```
IF Object_ID('dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne (
   [Week] int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   [Value] decimal(18,6) NOT NULL
);

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
   @f float = Rand(5.1415926535897932384626433832795028842),
   @Dt datetime = '17530101',
   @Week int;

WHILE @Dt <= '20140106' BEGIN
   INSERT dbo.ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne
   SELECT
      Format(@Dt, 'yyyy') + Right('0' + Convert(varchar(11), DateDiff(day, DateAdd(year, DateDiff(year, 0, @Dt), 0), @Dt) / 7 + 1), 2),
      Rand() * 151 - 76
   ;
   SET @Dt = DateAdd(day, 7, @Dt);
END;
```

This generates 13,620 weeks, from 175301 through 201401. I modified all the queries to select the `Week` values instead of the count, in the format `SELECT @Week = Expression ...` so that tests are not affected by returning rows to the client.

I tested only the gap-respecting, non-year-boundary-handling versions.

**Results**

```
             Query  Duration  CPU    Reads
------------------  --------  -----  ------
    ErikE-Preorder   27        31       40
       ErikE-CROSS   29        31       40
     ErikE-Join-IN   -------Awful---------
ErikE-Join-Revised   46        47    15069
    ErikE-Lead-Lag  104       109       40
              jods   12        16      120
  Transact Charlie   12        16      120
```

**Conclusions**

1. The reduced reads of the non-JOIN versions are not significant enough to warrant their increased complexity.
2. The table is so small that the performance *almost* doesn't matter. 261 years of weeks is insignificant, so a normal business operation won't see any performance problem even with a poor query.
3. I tested with an index on `Week` (which is more than reasonable), doing two separate `JOIN`s with a seek was far, far superior to any device to try to get the relevant related data in one swoop. Charlie and jods were spot on in their comments.
4. This data is not large enough to expose real differences between the queries in CPU and duration. The values above are representative, though at times the 31 ms were 16 ms and the 16 ms were 0 ms. Since the resolution is ~15 ms, this doesn't tell us much.
5. My tricky query techniques do perform better. They might be worth it in performance critical situations. But this is not one of those.
6. Lead and Lag may not always win. The presence of an index on the lookup value is probably what determines this. The ability to still pull prior/next values based on a certain order even when the order by value is not sequential may be one good use case for these functions.

Comment: Your 3rd query, the "one join" solution is not correct. It returns all weeks that are part of a negative range. That is: negative weeks that have a negative week before or after them. The OP wanted to count the number of such _ranges_. So if there are 4 negative weeks in a row, it should return "1". Your query doesn't achieve that. Regarding performance, although there is only one join, the performance is probably no better than the two joins solution if week is indexed; because you use a IN with 2 values, where each joins use only one equality.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how the 2nd query should actually work and looking at the fiddle results, it seems it doesn't work. It returns all rows that are part of a negative range, but again this doesn't solve the problem of counting the number of ranges.

Comment: The first query works and is clever. I would like to see how you tweak the row_number|s to work with holes in the data. Regarding performance I guess you have to test with big data sets. There is a reason those execution plans are rated costly: you do multiple sorts over the whole dataset. The bigger the dataset, the more I think the join solution with an indexed [week] column should be more efficient. The final consideration I have is that there is value in maintainability. Although those queries are clever, they are complicated and not obviously correct at first sight.

Comment: @jods Thank you for your comments. The requirements only say "number of 2 or more consecutive weeks", which wasn't really clear on the desired format. I will modify my queries to return only one row per instance. About performance considerations: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614431/how-can-i-detect-and-bound-changes-between-row-values-in-a-sql-table/13618019#13618019) for some related comments from me (especially at the end): I happen to agree with you about what is probably the best code--and opaque code for little benefit is not the first choice.

Comment: @jods Addressing actual performance, I plan to work up a much larger data set, add appropriate indexes, and do some testing. I expect that my `JOIN`less queries will win on reads every time, but will lose on CPU by some amount (maybe triple?), which may or may not matter, depending on how much absolute time it takes and whether the DB system is typically I/O bound or CPU bound.

Comment: Nice write up my man -- you should probably stick that analysis in a blog post though.

Comment: wow you really did put a lot of time into this. Thanks for the analysis! Seeing how you handled the gaps, I understand better why you 'lost' the year crossing as continuity in the numbers is important to your algorithm. This is also a good point for the JOIN solution, which can handle year crossing in a trivial way. I agree Correctness is always first, in my book Fast also comes last, but only if it's fast enough. As you say sometimes we have to dirty the code to get the required extra performance.

Comment: BTW you have interesting techniques... I learned some new patterns in your usage of APPLY|s, the VALUES one as well as the SELECT without a FROM.

Comment: @jods The year crossing is quite possible but I just don't have the formula I need. I meant `CROSS JOIN` a few times instead of `CROSS APPLY`...

Answer (score 1):

You can replace LEAD and LAG with a self-join.

The counting idea is basically to count start of negative sequences rather than trying to consider each row.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne W
LEFT OUTER JOIN ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne Prev
  ON W.week = Prev.week + 1
INNER JOIN ConsecutiveNegativeWeekTestOne Next
  ON W.week = Next.week - 1
WHERE W.value < 0 
  AND (Prev.value IS NULL OR Prev.value > 0)
  AND Next.value < 0
```

Note that I simply did "week + 1", which would not work when there is a year change.

Comment: Nice answer thanks, clever use of joins. Both answers are good and I would say this one is using syntax that I find more common.

Comment: I think their execution plans should be very similar if not identical anyway, so it's really a matter of syntax preference.

Comment: There is no need for 3 table scans. This problem can be solved with normal SQL in just one `JOIN`. In fact, it can be done without a `JOIN` at all.

Comment: @ErikE: if week is indexed this solution is quite cheap. One full table scan the two joins come from the index. See my comments on your solutions. Only the first one solves the problem correctly, as you say yourself it doesn't handle holes in the data, it's not very obvious and I'm not even sure that it really performs better on big data sets.

Comment: Each of my non-join answers can be easily modified to handle holes in the data (and lose year boundary-crossing), so that is not a real issue. However, for what it's worth I now see why you are joining twice, because you are focusing on only the *starting* weeks, not on pulling *all* the weeks--and that does change things.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Your query wins in my book, as the best combination of clarity, conciseness, and performance.