# How to get the difference between two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We store the experimental data of the system in every one second. we also store Date-Time , system_ON_Status along with other parameters. The system is switched ON as per the requirement in a day (May be 3-4 times).

Now we need to generate the query to display the start and stop time of the experiment.

The system_ON_Status Field is stored as a boolean in SQL.

True for ON and False for OFF.

Thanks

We are using SQL SERVER 2008 R2

```
Date_Time                 System_ON_Status
2014-03-04 16:01:01:000     0
2014-03-04 16:01:02:000     0
2014-03-04 16:01:03:000     0
2014-03-04 16:01:04:000     0
2014-03-04 16:01:05:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:06:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:07:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:08:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:09:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:10:000     0
2014-03-04 16:01:11:000     0
2014-03-04 16:01:12:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:13:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:14:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:15:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:16:000     0
2014-03-04 16:01:17:000     0
2014-03-04 16:01:18:000     0
2014-03-04 16:01:19:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:20:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:21:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:22:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:23:000     1
2014-03-04 16:01:24:000     1
```

The output must be:
1) Start of the experiment i.e 16:01:05:000 
and End of experiment  16:01:09:000
System was operated for : Difference between 16:01:05:000 - 16:01:09:000 
4sec

2) Start of the experiment i.e 16:01:12:000 
and End of experiment  16:01:15:000
System was operated for : Difference between 16:01:05:000 - 16:01:09:000 
3sec

2) Start of the experiment i.e 16:01:19:000 
and End of experiment  16:01:24:000
System was operated for : Difference between 16:01:05:000 - 16:01:09:000 
5sec

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You might want to detail your data structure so people can help you better. That being said, you probably want to look at aggregate functions, so a search for `GROUP BY` and using `MIN` / `MAX` to determine the start and end times accordingly will probably work

Comment: `select max(Time),min(Time),max(Time)-min(Time) as Time_GAP from table`?

Comment: Please edit your question to show sample data, desired results, and tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: You say you store the date/time and status "along with other parameters". What are those other parameters? Can you identify each experiment with another field? With the data presented it's difficult to separate one experiment from another.

Comment: Other parameters are like Voltage , current of the power supplies etc.  Can we compare the two rows and identify the change in the System_ON_Status i.e from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 and take the difference of the time.

Answer (score 0):

The following query gives you the start and end times of each experiment. It includes the time where the `system_on_status` changes back to zero, as this is confirmation the experiment has ended. In the case of the last experiment it has not yet ended (there's no zero for `system_on_status`) so the end time is `NULL`.

```
SELECT  FromTime = MIN(D.log_date)
       ,X.ToTime
       ,D.system_on_status
FROM    Experiment_Log D
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                ToTime = D2.log_date
                      FROM      Experiment_Log D2
                      WHERE     D.log_date < D2.log_date
                                AND D.[system_on_status] <> D2.[system_on_status]
                      ORDER BY  D2.log_date
                    ) X
WHERE   D.system_on_status = 1
GROUP BY X.ToTime
       ,D.system_on_status
ORDER BY FromTime;
```

Output from this for your data:

```
FromTime             ToTime               system_on_status
2014-03-04 16:01:05  2014-03-04 16:01:10  1
2014-03-04 16:01:12  2014-03-04 16:01:16  1
2014-03-04 16:01:19  NULL                 1
```

I can't really claim any glory for this, I took the query from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13618019/243925) and modified it for your table. So if you want to up-vote go and give ErikE the rep! :)