# How do I select rows between rows that match a condition?

Tags: sql

This questions is a simplified version of a problem I have at work. I'm using a custom database that supports all standard SQL queries. I suppose this question applies to any RDMS that supports SQL though.

Suppose I have the table `events`, including three columns: `event_type` (string), `details` (string), and `timestamp` (integer).

One of the events of interest is power outage. The system logs the power status every once in a while. If there's a power outage, "outage" will be logged. Otherwise, "good" will be logged.

Another event of interest is access. Whenever somebody accesses a room, the room that was entered will be logged as well.

I want to select all rooms entered during a  power outages.

For example, I have the following rows.

```
event_type | details        | timestamp
---------------------------------------
power      | good           | 14
access     | room 6         | 13
power      | good           | 12
access     | room 5         | 11
access     | room 4         | 10
power      | outage         | 9
power      | outage         | 8
access     | room 3         | 7
power      | outage         | 6
access     | room 2         | 5
power      | good           | 4
access     | room 1         | 3
power      | outage         | 2
access     | room 0         | 1
power      | good           | 0
```

I want to get the following rows.

```
event_type | details        | timestamp
---------------------------------------

power      | good           | 12
access     | room 5         | 11
access     | room 4         | 10
power      | outage         | 9
power      | outage         | 8
access     | room 3         | 7
power      | outage         | 6

power      | good           | 4
access     | room 1         | 3
power      | outage         | 2
```

The current way I'm doing this feels like I'm not using SQL the right way.

First I get the timestamp for a power outage. Next, I get the minimum timestamp that the power came back after that outage. Finally, I select all events between the two timestamps. After that, I find the next outage timestamp after the power came back. Repeat.

Another way I did it was to just download all the rows to a flat file, then use a Python script to filter out the rows I want in a procedural way.

Is there a better way to get the rows I need?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff As I explained in the question, I'm using a custom database. I suppose it's similar to MySQL. Can I just tag it with MySQL?

Comment: @Russell in your description you say will appear `BAD` but instead you use `OUTAGE` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for pointing that out. Let me edit the question.

Comment: I don't suppose you have windowing functions like `RANK()`, `ROW_NUMBER()` and `DENSE_RANK()` do you?

Comment: @ErikE That would be too easy :) But lets wait for OP

Comment: @ErikE Unfortunately no. Just for the sake of learning, if I do have windowing functions, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working query for you ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8fdea/1)):

```
SELECT
  E.*
FROM
  dbo.Events E
WHERE
  E.event_type IN ('access', 'power')
  AND (
    SELECT TOP 1 details
    FROM dbo.Events E2
    WHERE
      E.timestampid >= E2.timestampid
      AND E2.event_type = 'power'
    ORDER BY E2.timestampid DESC
  ) = 'outage'
;
```

I used SQL Server syntax but it's just as easy to pop a `LIMIT 1` in there for MySQL. Regarding windowing functions, I don't have the time or energy to come up with the answer at the moment, but if you'll refer to [this question and my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614431/how-can-i-detect-and-bound-changes-between-row-values-in-a-sql-table/13618019) you will see one of the techniques I've used for a similar problem.

Also, note that how to handle the data at the beginning of the set is a question. If the first events were `{ access, room 0 }, { power, outage }`, would you want the `room 0` row to be in the result set or not? Even `{ access, room 0 }, { power, good }` might also be a candidate for inclusion at the start of the set, since it *could* be the case that the power was out at the start--we don't have that information in this data. If you want to include rows in either of these cases, please let me know and I can update my query.

Comment: why you include `E.event_type IN ('access', 'power')` ? I only see those two event_type anyway

Comment: He said it was part of a larger system and implied there are many event_types. Those conditions are thus a hint about what else may be needed to filter out the other data that is bound to be present.

Comment: @ErikE I originally didn't have the requirement to handle the data at the beginning of the set. If it's not too much to ask, may I know how you would handle power outages from the beginning?

Comment: @Russell Please answer what result you want for the scenarios I mentioned, the two proposed set starts. Only then can I help you with a query.

Comment: @ErikE I want the first power status to be included no matter what even if it was good, which  means including timestamp 0 and 1.

Comment: Then add an OR condition? I presume you don't know the value of the first time stamp?

Answer (score 2):

You can identify all rows where the previous "power" row was for "outage" and not "good".

I think that gets you the information you want.

```
select e.*
from events e
where 'outage' = (select e2.details
                  from events e2
                  where e2.event_type = 'power' and
                        e2.timestamp < e.timestamp
                  order by e2.timestamp desc
                  limit 1
                 ) or
      e.event_type = 'power';
```

Comment: [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/99476/2) This almost work. But miss the start block row. For this case rows with time 2 and 6

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . My understanding is that the OP only wants rows that are "access" rows, not "power" rows.

Comment: Im was using the Desire output table provided by OP

Comment: The original question shows the desired output, and includes timestamps 2 and 6.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . That is just slightly different logic in the outer `where`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! The output I wanted was the example output rows I gave, but I do realize the question stated was vague too. Sorry about that. I've upvoted this answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.  You may need to play with defaults for NULL values returned by the first select statement inside the where for the case when the power goes off and hasn't come back on yet (do you want this to show up or not?).  This is most likely less efficient than implementations that utilize more powerful functions (limit, row_number etc).

```
SELECT event_type, details, timestamp
FROM events t1
WHERE
(event_type = 'power' AND details = 'outage')
OR
(SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
 FROM events t2 
 WHERE t2.event_type = 'power' AND 
       t2.details = 'outage' AND 
       t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp)
>
(SELECT MAX(timestamp)
 FROM events t2
 WHERE t2.event_type = 'power' AND
       t2.details = 'good' AND
       t2.timestamp < t1.timestamp)
```