# Selecting records where change has occurred from previous row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a psql table called `test` with three attribute columns.  The first type is an integer and the second is a character and the third is an integer

My goal is only to select the records where state has changed from `A` or `B` to `C` - in other words, where the current state is `C` and the previous state was either `A` or `B`, ordered by `id` and record number.

How would one write such a query in psql?

```
 id state record
  1     C      1
  1     A      2
  1     C      3
  1     A      4
  1     C      5
  1     A      6
  1     B      7
  2     C      8
  2     C      9
  2     C     10
  2     B     11
  2     C     12
  2     C     13
  2     C     14
  3     A     15
  3     C     16
  3     B     17
  3     A     18
  3     A     19
  3     A     20
  3     A     21
  3     C     22
  3     A     23
  3     B     24
  3     B     25
```

SELECTING on the above table would return something like this:

```
id state record
  1     C      3
  1     C      5
  2     C     12
  3     C     16
  3     C     22
```

Comment: I think this would help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614431/how-can-i-detect-and-bound-changes-between-row-values-in-a-sql-table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method uses `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(t.state) over (partition by t.id order by t.record) as prev_state
      from t
     ) t
where t.state = 'C' and prev_state in ('A', 'B');
```

Another uses a self-join:

```
select t.*
from t join
     t tprev
     on t.id = tprev.id and t.record = t.record + 1
where t.state = 'C' and tprev.state in ('A', 'B')
```